# Retrofit.Callback's success() and failure() in case of two interface implementations in same Activity

Tags: java, android, interface, retrofit

I am currently writing an app that connects to a server to make POST requests. For this reason, I have created multiple Retrofit interfaces for various network operations. I have one that performs registration: I take the username, e-mail etc, make a POST request and then as a final parameter I have a Callback (RegistrationResult is a POJO that accepts "success" or "failure" in a class variable). This interface looks like this:

```
public interface RegistrationInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/apiregistration.php")
    void connect(@Field("country") String country,
            @Field("state") String state, @Field("email") String email, 
            @Field("pwd") String password,
            Callback<RegistrationResult> resp);

}
```

Now, because I'm going to use GCM for push notifications, I have another interface that sends the registration id of the particular device to the server and, again, gets a response back. That interface looks like this:

```
public interface SendRegIDInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/apiregid.php")
    void connect(@Field("reg_id") String reg_id,

    Callback<RegIDResult> resp);

}
```

So far, so good. The problem arises when I try to create implementations of both interfaces in the same class. Let's say I have an Activity that, for some reason, should use implementations from both interfaces. So I have this:

```
public class MessageActivity extends Activity implements Callback {

 public void onCreate(Bundle firebug) {

 RestAdapter restAdapter1 = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(endpoint).build();
 RegistrationInterface regInter = restAdapter1.create(RegistrationInterface.class);
 regInter.connect(// parameters here, MessageActivity.this);

 RestAdapter restAdapter2 = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(endpoint).build();
 SendRegIDInterface regIDInter = restAdapter2.create(SendRegIDInterface.class);
 regIDInter.connect(reg_id, MessageActivity.this); 



  }




@Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void success(Object arg0, Response arg1) {

}

}
```

My problem is this: where do the overridden methods (failure and success) of the Retrofit.Callback interface correspond? Since I'm having two implementations of Retrofit interfaces in the same Activity, how can I distinguish what gets returned in, eg. the success() method?  Is it the response from the RegistrationInterface implementation or the response from the SendRegIDInterface that's contained in the Callback's success() method's arguments? As long as I only had an implementation of the RegistrationInterface interface in the Activity, everything was clear: the success() method's arguments contain the server's response to the registration request. Now that I'm using a second interface implementation (SendRegIDInterface) I'm super-confused!

Or am I going completely wrong about this?

Comment: Check this response that decouples the request and callback. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31219041/560040

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need a bit more separation. If you want to place the callbacks in your activity, the business logic will mess too much with the UI related things.

When I use Retrofit I do it this way (will demonstrate it with your code): First, I have a `RegistrationClient.java`, where I define all the endpoints for the API:

```
public interface RegistrationClient {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/apiregistration.php")
    void connect(@Field("country") String country,
            @Field("state") String state, @Field("email") String email, 
            @Field("pwd") String password,
            Callback<RegistrationResult> resp);

}
```

In this case, it is only one endpoint, but there will be cases, where there will be more, e.g.:

1. `GET /persons/{id}`
2. `POST /persons/`
3. `PUT /persons/{id}`

When I got my client, then I create a model for the interface. I would name it `RegistrationModel` in your case:

```
public class RegistrationModel {

  private RegistrationClient _client;

  public RegistrationModel() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder() ... // create an adapter
    _client = restAdapter.create(RegistrationClient.class);
  }

  public void connect(String country, String state, String email, String password) { 
    // you can add an additional callback parameter for returning info to the caller.
    _client.connect(country, state, email, password, new Callback<RegistrationResult> {

      @Override
      public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        // Do the essential things, and do a callback to the caller if needed
      }

      @Override
      public void success(RegistrationResult result, Response response) {
        // Do the essential things, and do a callback to the caller if needed
      }
   }
}
```

Then I would hold a singleton reference to each of the models using a my own [service locator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx), or using dependency injection (with [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/)).
So from your activity, the call would be something like this:

```
...
ServiceLocator.getRegistrationModel().connect(country, state, email, password);
...
```

Or if you added your own callback:

```
...
ServiceLocator.getRegistrationModel().connect(country, state, email, password,
  new RegistrationCallback(boolean result) {
  // do something.
  }
);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! This is a great way to go about it!